# HTML in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript popUp function...

```
popUp(title, body){
    $('body').append('<div id="popupWindow"><div class="close"></div>
        <h2 class="title">'+title+'</h2>
        <div class="body">'+body+'</div>
        </div>");
    // then on $('.close').click(func(){ remove() etc... } );
    // and keyCode == 13 remove();
}
```

that inserts the two arguments into popup window that is then inserted into the html of the document.  I had the idea of having a `<form>` as `body` but it craps out??

I have tried various things and it would appear to be the html as the argument which is causing the problem.  I have limited javascript/jQuery experience, so any help you guys/gals can give would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Si

It's not a complete copy - However your right, there was a stray quote i hadnt escaped in the form thanks guys (hour well spent for a typo...)

Comment: Possibly a typo, but the end of your html string is using the wrong type of quote.

Comment: And you can't have new lines in JS strings

Comment: Any reason you can't use the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) plugin?

Comment: @Quentin you can, if you escape them with \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an identifier for your form and use it in JavaScript code.

```
<form id="myform"></form>


popUp(title, body){
    $('#myform').append('<div id="popupWindow"><div class="close"></div>
        <h2 class="title">'+title+'</h2>
        <div class="body">'+body+'</div>
        </div>');
    // then on $('.close').click(func(){ remove() etc... } );
    // and keyCode == 13 remove();
}
```

By the way, there was an error with quotes in your append statement.

Answer (score 1):

Is popUp a function? You also have some line-break issues. Personally, I would use jQuery to construct your elements... it's much more elegant.

```
function popUp(title, body){

    var $popup = $('<div />').attr('id', 'popupWindow');
    var $close = $('<div />').addClass('close');
    var $title = $('<h2 />').addClass('title').text(title);
    var $body = $('<div />').addClass('body').html(body);

    $popup.append($close).append($title).append($body);
    $('body').append($popup);
    // To append to a form, you can target it here instead of 'body'

}

popUp('My Title', 'Some <strong>body</strong> content');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem using single and double quotes in append method, use ASCII, codes like :

```
 + String.fromCharCode(34) + title + String.fromCharCode(34) +
```

**String.fromCharCode(34)** is used for **"** and  **String.fromCharCode(39)** is used for **'**.